# Why won't my SemVer NSRegularExpression run?

Tags: swift, cocoa, runtime-error, nsregularexpression, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to make a regex that matches a [semantic version (SemVer) 2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html). This is my first try:

```
^(?'major'\d+)\.(?'minor'\d+)(?:\.(?'patch'\d+))?(?:-(?'preRelease'(?:(?'preReleaseId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?(?:\+(?'build'(?:(?'buildId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?$
```

<sup>[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/Tsku4b/2/)</sup>

This passes my smoke tests, but when I try to actually make it a [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression), I get this:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “^(?'major'\d+)\.(?'minor'\d+)(?:\.(?'patch'\d+))?(?:-(?'preRelease'(?:(?'preReleaseId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?(?:\+(?'build'(?:(?'buildId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?$” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue=^(?'major'\d+)\.(?'minor'\d+)(?:\.(?'patch'\d+))?(?:-(?'preRelease'(?:(?'preReleaseId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?(?:\+(?'build'(?:(?'buildId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.?)+))?$}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181
```

Why? I can't find anything online about what `NSRegularExpression` expects/accepts, so I don't know what I did wrong here.

---

Swift code:

```swift
public static let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:
    "^(?'major'\\d+)\\." +
    "(?'minor'\\d+)" +
    "(?:\\.(?'patch'\\d+))?" +
    "(?:-(?'preRelease'(?:(?'preReleaseId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\\.?)+))?" +
    "(?:\\+(?'build'(?:(?'buildId'[0-9A-Za-z-]+)\\.?)+))?$",
                                                   options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Comment: Show your code for instantiating the `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: OK... it shouldn't reveal anything special tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use named groups in your regex. `NSRegularExpression` named groups use angle brackets rather than single quotes which you have in your regex. Try using the syntax

```
`(?<groupName>...)`
```

for your named capture groups.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here a regex that meets that spec. I used PCRE style for illustration purposes: named groups. You may need to remove the `<groupnames>` and make normal groups out of them.
You may want to add `^` and `$` to match start and end of sting:

```
(?<version_core>(?<major>(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+))\.(?<minor>(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+))\.(?<patch>(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)))(?:-(?<pre_release>(?:0|[1-9A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9A-Za-z-][0-9A-Za-z-]*))*))?(?:\+(?<build>[0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_ooNAbziBepD4tuM)

Comment: Might wanna upload that image directly to SO :)

Comment: Also, your regex doesn't match `1.0`, which is a valid SemVer since the PATCH is not required. Here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/bINTxOgO8E88Z5n_

Comment: @BenLeggiero `1.0` is not valid - patch version is needed - https://github.com/semver/semver/blob/master/semver.md#backusnaur-form-grammar-for-valid-semver-versions